# How run function after the hook completes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to build a code that, depending on the result coming from the Hook, redirects to a different page.

So my hook uses the code below:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { database } from "../../services/firebase"

type UserDetails = {
    id: string,
    userID: string,
    userName: string,
    userEmail: string,
    userAvatar: string,
    userDescription: string,
    userSkills: string,
    userPhone: string,
    userTitle: string,
    userInterests: string
}

export function useGetUserProfile(userid: string | undefined){

    const [ userDef, setUserDef ] = useState<UserDetails>()
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState<boolean>(true)


    useEffect(()=>{
        const userRef = database.ref(`users/${userid}`);

        userRef.on('value', userInfo =>{
            const databaseUser = userInfo.val();

            const userDetails: UserDetails = {
                id: databaseUser.key,
                userID: databaseUser.userID,
                userName: databaseUser.userName,
                userEmail: databaseUser.userEmail,
                userAvatar: databaseUser.userAvatar,
                userDescription: databaseUser.userDescription,
                userSkills: databaseUser.userSkills, 
                userPhone: databaseUser.userPhone,
                userTitle: databaseUser.userTitle,
                userInterests: databaseUser.userInterests
            }

            setUserDef(userDetails);
            setLoading(false);
        })
    },[userid])
    return{userDef, loading}
}
```

And here is my page function:

```js
const [ userId, setUserID ] = useState<string | undefined>("")
    
    const { userDef, loading } = useGetUserProfile(userId)

    async function handleAuthGoogle(){
        
        if(!user){
            await singIngWithGoogle();
        }
        
        if(!loading){
            await setUserID(user?.id)
            if(userDef != undefined){
                navigate('/home');
            }else{
                navigate(`/Profile/Editar/${userId}`)
            }   
        }
    }
```

The function completes before the hook loads. My question is, how do I code it in order to wait the hook completes loading to then run the function? I tried using while, but didn't work well.

Comment: The problem is that the firebase function is asynchronous and page function is synchronous. Take a look at the Promises and the firebase docs on returning Promises [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions)

Answer (score 1):

I think your function `useGetUserProfile()` will return undefined before it's set. As a solution:

1. I'd suggest you consider a Promise-based return from the `useGetUserProfile()` function. and get it in your main component with `.then()`.
2. you need to catch it if it's `undefined` or rejected.

As reference here is the sample code:

```
// Getter
const GetUserData =(userid: string | undefined):Promise<any> => {
    const [ userDef, setUserDef ] = useState<UserDetails>()
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState<boolean>(true)

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        const userRef = database.ref(`users/${userid}`);
        // if we NOT got all data needed
        if(userRef===undefined){
            setLoading(false);
            reject("user not found")
        }
        else{
        userRef.on('value', userInfo =>{
            const databaseUser = userInfo.val();

            const userDetails: UserDetails = {
                id: databaseUser.key,
                userID: databaseUser.userID,
                userName: databaseUser.userName,
                userEmail: databaseUser.userEmail,
                userAvatar: databaseUser.userAvatar,
                userDescription: databaseUser.userDescription,
                userSkills: databaseUser.userSkills, 
                userPhone: databaseUser.userPhone,
                userTitle: databaseUser.userTitle,
                userInterests: databaseUser.userInterests
            }

            setLoading(false);
            resolve(userDetails);
        }
})
}
```

And you would call it from the main component like this:

```
const [userId, setUserID] = useState<string | undefined>("");
const { userDef, loading } = useGetUserProfile(userId);

async function handleAuthGoogle() {
  if (!user) {
    await singIngWithGoogle();
  }
  GetUserData(user?.id).then(response=>{
    navigate(`/Profile/Editar/${userId}`);
  }).catch(e=>{
    console.log(e)
    navigate("/home");
  })
  
}
```

Comment: Same think, it starts GetUserData before complete login and get all user data, then no rotes are used

Comment: could you specify, what code you want to wait for before `GetUserData()` is ready? I can't clearly understand then

Comment: Sure, we have two waitings actually. the really fist is the `signInWithGoogle` function, which will connect the user and provide the user information (then the `user?.id` will have data), then it makes us free to run `GetUserData` witch we should also wait to complete and redirect to the best rote according to the data returned.

Answer (score 0):

A component that has useGetUserProfile cannot be loaded until you have access to userId.

```
const Page = () => {
const [ userId, setUserID ] = useState<string | undefined>("");
async function handleAuthGoogle(){
  if(!user){
    await singIngWithGoogle();
  }

  setUserID(user?.id)  
}

useEffect(() => handleAuthGoogle(), []);

return userId ? <SignInRouter userId={userId} /> : <Whatever />;
}

// And then

const SignInRouter = ({ userId }) => {
  const { userDef, loading } = useGetUserProfile(userId);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && userDef) navigate('');
    else navigate('');
  }, [loading, userDef]);
}
```

Or update the hook to react to userId becoming available.

```
export function useGetUserProfile(userid: string | undefined){

    const [ userDef, setUserDef ] = useState<UserDetails>()
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState<boolean>(true)


    useEffect(()=>{
        // Don't attempt a fetch until an id is available
        if (!userid) return;
    
        // rest of stuff
    },[userid])
    return{userDef, loading}
}
```

Comment: Didn’t work. It loads the function before get the user info. Then no rotes are used.